# Static resource reload with akka-http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, hotswap

In short: is it possible to reload static resources using akka-http?

A bit more:

- I have Scala project.
- I'm using `App` object to launch my `Main`
  class.
- I'm using `getFromResourceDirectory` to locate my resource
  folder.

What I would like to have is to hot-swap my static resources during development. 
For example, I have `index.html` or `application.js`, which I change and I want to see changes after I refresh my browser without restarting my server. What is the best practise of doing such thing?

I know that `Play!` allows that, but don't want to base my project on `Play!` only because of that.

Comment: Take a look at sbt-revolver plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

1. Easiest: use the `getFromDirectory` directive instead when running locally and point it to the path where your files you want to 'hotload' are, it serves them directly from the file system, so every time you change a file and load it through Akka HTTP it will be the latest version.
2. `getFromResourceDirectory` loads files from the classpath, the resources are available because SBT copies them into the class directory under `target`  every time you build (`copyResources`). You could configure sbt using `unmanagedClasspath` to make it include the static resource directory in the classpath. If you want to package the resources in the artifact when running `package` however this would require some more sbt-trixery (if you just put `src/resources` in `unmanagedClasspath` it will depend on classpath ordering if the copied ones or the modified ones are used).

Comment: Wow, that was so easy.. :) I was using 'getFromResourceDirectory'. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get it to work by adding to unmanagedClasspath so I instead used getFromDirectory. You can use getFromDirectory as a fallback if getFromResourceDirectory fails like this.

```
val route =
  pathSingleSlash {
    getFromResource("static/index.html") ~
    getFromFile("../website/static/index.html")
  } ~
  getFromResourceDirectory("static") ~
  getFromDirectory("../website/static")
```

First it tries to look up the file in the static resource directory and if that fails, then checks if ../website/static has the file.

Answer (score 1):

The below code try to find the file in the directory "**staticContentDir**". If the file is found, it is sent it back to the client. If it is not found, it tries by fetching the file from the directory "**site**" in the classpath.
The user url **is: http://server:port/site/path/to/file.ext**

/site/ comes from "staticPath"

```
  val staticContentDir = calculateStaticPath()
  val staticPath = "site"
  val routes = pathPrefix(staticPath) {
    entity(as[HttpRequest]) { requestData =>
      val fullPath = requestData.uri.path
      encodeResponse {
        if (Files.exists(staticContentDir.resolve(fullPath.toString().replaceFirst(s"/$staticPath/", "")))) {
          getFromBrowseableDirectory(staticContentDir.toString)
        } else {
          getFromResourceDirectory("site")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I hope it is clear.